# How to connect to MS SQL DB using Linux Red Hat release 6.10, export records from a view for a date into .csv file and place it in Linux file system

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, linux, shell

I need to connect to MS SQL database using Linux (Red Hat release 6.10) and look up on a view present in database. I need to export records from this view for a particular date into .csv file and place it in Linux file system.

For retrieving a particular date records I need to apply filter conditions on the Date-Timestamp column of this view. How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: these are a lot of questions, I suggest creating a question for each of them in stead of putting all in one question. Also you should show what you have tried and where you are stuck. That would make it much easier for us to help you, and you would get the help you need much faster

Comment: Use [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) with queryout? You can of course do that with python too, since you've also tagged it.

Comment: Your question is really missing all the details about what the problem is, or what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi @JamesZ your link on bcp is actually given me a big picture of how things are done import export of data, installation process ect. For your another question, I only have this requirement in hand and did not know where to start and how to proceed, hence I have asked this general question here. :) I only know that there is MS SQL database which has its own view (this DB is managed by external team not me) I have Linux server and I have to access from thsi Linux sever the view inside MS SQL database and export data into a .csv file for a particular day with filter condition on date column.